# Register a hotkey to simulate mouse click on an object in a dll web application

Tags: internet-explorer, dll, asp-classic, keyboard-shortcuts, registerhotkey

**Disclaimer**

I am in no means an expert in web technology, nor am I too familiar with .asp, .dll and other MS shenanigans, so don't be surprised to find weird/illogical (but hopefully meaningful enough) constructs bellow.

**Background**

I'm working, along with my colleagues, on a IE-only dll-packed .aspx IFRAMEd CRM application. What that (was supposed to) mean is that it's only accessible via IE, and the url is in the form of: *http://internal-ip/foo/bar/something.dll?FOO=BAR*, and that the page displayed consists of misc HTML background items and two IFRAMEs, containing important application stuff. Being CRM, it requires repetitive actions hundreds of times per day (insert new customer, update a customer, lookup various information about them etc).

**Problem**

Every one of those actions requires multiple complicated menu navigations through the software in order to finally click on the relevant menu item and wait for the required page to load (so complicated, that they are estimated to consume more then 75% of total time spent completing an action).

**Idea**

In order to speed things up (and thus increase efficiency) I came up with an idea to somehow implement keyboard shortcuts that would act the same way as the click on the menu item does. The idea seems simple enough, but I don't know where to start.

**Attempted solution**

If it were a standard web page I would create a greasemonkey script that does $("#menu_item").trigger("click") when I press ctrl+something, but I cannot do that for two reasons:

1. No greasemonkey (Trixie doesn't work), and
2. Can't examine any objects or DOM navigate though them because they are in an IFRAME, so that's as far and as deep as I can go with firebug lite.

In order to solve the first issue, I've managed to open the application with Firefox using IE Tab 2, and sure enough, the application works, but the Greasemonkey scripts don't - even a simple alert("a") script on page load doesn't execute (maybe because the page wrapped in a .dll).

**Conclusion**

So it seems to me that I won't be able to push through with my original plan, so is there anything else I could try? I have limited access to the remote server where the application is located, and can only peak into the files in hope to catch a glimpse of something that would be helpful, but that is too time-consuming and probably not fruitful in the end.

I'm hoping there is a simple enough solution (as this should be a pretty common feature) to avoid tumbling through hundreds of files or learning how to reverse-engineer .dll's. Has anyone been in a similar situation, and if not, how would you try to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the app is running in a brower no matter what platform it is hosted on the server is spitting out HTML to which Javascript is going to help you here for the shortcuts.

You should check out a few of these (using the jquery lib):

[Keyboard shortcuts with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery)

[Keyboard shortcut for hyperlink (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181624/keyboard-shortcut-for-hyperlink-jquery)

http://www.stepanreznikov.com/js-shortcuts/

The click on the menu is going to execute a function most likely, I would suggest executing the function with the keypress rather than trying to emulate a click.

Comment: The problem is that I have no control over the source code, so I'm looking for a way to successfully "inject" javascript code for that purpose. I have tried to do that with Trixie or IE Tab 2 + Greasemonkey (the app is limited to IE), but even the simplest  javascript code fail to execute, for reasons unknown to me (my best guess is that .dll wrapping might be causing problems).

Comment: You only will need inject one line to get a javascript file included. You just need to add this in the header, "generally" the header files should be seperate to the actual DLL, even the existing JS files "should" be external.

Can you post the HTML from <HTML> upto </HEAD> and we can take a look at what files are being included and what you could be able to edit.

Comment: If you want to inject HTML you could do it with a chrome extension if you can limit your users to Chrome.

Comment: The website cannot be opened from Chrome, Opera or Safari. Only IE and Firefox (by IETab 2, which somehow renders the page using actual IE). There's a bunch of .js files, but I'm very reluctant to touch the source files since doing so might void the support contract we have.

So the preferred way would be to resolve problems with Trixie and IEtab2, or find a similar way to inject javascript at runtime, if such a way exists.

Comment: Understand, but injecting is going to be tricky, you might get IE to work via their plugins but you wont be able to get FF working if it is loading via another plugin. I recommend you talk to your supplier as you would only have to add 5 lines to the top of one of the existing JS files to load your JS file: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html is an example, you could document this and show the company. You would then load your JS files to add the hot keys. More than willing to write it for you.

Comment: The other alternative is via the webserver itself if you have access to that, if you are running IIS for example you can inject footers into all pages, you might be able to inject a JS file load this way, the only down side to this is that it will be injected outside of the </html> close tag and *might* not work 100% as advertised and testing would be required.

Comment: It's not the coding itself that is the problem, but the fact that we are not allowed to compromise the functionality of the product we're using. So a little extra .js code on a few clients would be ok (because of it's isolated impact), but asking them to include our .js in the product would mean "ok, but if something stops working it's your responsibility because we don't have full control over our product anymore". As for the server side, if we can limit the injection to only a few ip addresses it could work (script in body is ok), I'll look it up. Thanks!

Comment: Ok good luck, If I answered your question please flag as answered in the comments :)